# Crystal Report Returning a blank, when Expected return should be a date

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm trying to utilize some Custom Fields in my Database to have Crystal return some associated dates. The logic works when every record contains data. But as soon as I leave one record's custom field blank it breaks.

```
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = ""   , {PO.PromisedDate} + 45    , 
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C1" , {PO._C1ETAPort} +10 , 
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C2" , {PO._C2ETAPort} +10 ,
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C3" , {PO._C3ETAPort} +10 ,
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C4" , {PO._C4ETAPort} +10 ,
IIF(    {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C5" , {PO._C5ETAPort} +10 ,
DATE(0,0,0) ))))))
```

See Below expected Return -

[image: Expected Return -]

However, If I would remove a single records "C" Value the below occurs. This same issue happens when a "Special Instruction" or _C*ETAPort field is left blank.

Issue -

[image: Issue]

I would have expected that the PromiseDate logic would have taken place for those empty values, and that the C1 Logic would still be in place. However, it seems to crash here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best answer. However, sometimes when utilizing the IIF function I do not receive the expected return. Instead - using the IF THEN ELSE statement I do.

```
IF ISNULL ( {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} ) 
THEN {PO.PromisedDate} + 45 
ELSE

IF {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C1"
THEN {PO._C1ETAPort} + 10
ELSE

IF {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C2"
THEN {PO._C2ETAPort} + 10
ELSE

IF {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C3"
THEN {PO._C3ETAPort} + 10
ELSE

IF {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C4"
THEN {PO._C4ETAPort} + 10
ELSE

IF {PODetail.SpecialInstructions} = "C5"
THEN {PO._C5ETAPort} + 10
ELSE

DATE (0,0,0)
```

Comment: You are not supposed to answer your own questions :) IIF() calculates all parts of expression beforehand and if you encounter any NULL values, then it is possible that entire result is NULL value. Either use some variables to get rid of NULL values, use IsNull() checks always or check `Convert NULL values to default` in report options (if you actually don't need null values).

Comment: You're right. I believe I should have check for a null value last therefore all other expressions are checked beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing the formula to a CASE statement.  It will be easier to read and troubleshoot, while simplifying your logic.

```
Select {PODetail.SpecialInstructions}
   Case "C1" : {PO._C1ETAPort} + 10
   Case "C2" : {PO._C2ETAPort} + 10
   Case "C3" : {PO._C3ETAPort} + 10
   Case "C4" : {PO._C4ETAPort} + 10
   Case "C5" : {PO._C5ETAPort} + 10
   Default   : {PO.PromisedDate} + 45
```

This eliminates the need to check for NULL.  When the data in the SpecialInstructions field is evaluated with this CASE statement if it doesn't equal one of your five C# values, then it simply defaults to your PromisedDate plus 45.  However, if you need logic that handles the default value differently than it would a NULL value, then I would recommend using a Formula Field to test for NULL values and returns a unique non-NULL value, then use that Formula Field in the Select statement within this CASE statement.  CASE statements in Crystal Report executes straight comparisons, so NULL values won't work well due to data type mismatching.

Comment: I have never used CASE expressions before in the past. However, this looks much cleaner and I will have to play with this type of syntax asap. Also - When I decided to use the entire IF Statement rather than the IIF Syntax - I was able to have the expected return I need. Thanks for your detailed explanation. I will start utilizing CASE in other scenarios to better familiarize myself. Thanks again!